# Index pdf documents in Solr from C# client

Tags: c#, pdf, tomcat, solr, solrnet

Basically I'm trying to index word or pdf documents in Solr and found the ExtractingRequestHandler, but can't figure out how to write code in c# that performs the HTTP POST request like in the Solr wiki: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler.

I've installed Solr 3.4 on Tomcat 7 (7.0.22) using the files from the example/solr directory in the Solr zip and I haven't altered anything. The ExtractingRequestHandler should be configured out of the box in the solrconfig.xml and ready to use, right?

Can some of you give an C# (HttpWebRequest) example of how you make the HTTP POST request and upload a PDF file like it is done using curl in the Solr wiki?

I've look all over this site and many others trying to find an example or a tutorial on how this is done, but haven't found anything.

**EDIT:**

I finally managed to get it to work using SolrNet!

In order for it to work you need to copy this to a lib-folder in your Solr installation directory from the Solr zip:

- apache-solr-cell-3.4.0.jar file from the dist folder
- content of contrib\extraction\lib directory

With SolrNet 0.4.0 beta 2, this code does the job:

```
Startup.Init<IndexDocument>("YOUR-SOLR-SERVICE-PATH");
var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<IndexDocument>>();

using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("FILE-PATH-FOR-THE-FILE-TO-BE-INDEXED"))
{
    var response =
        solr.Extract(
            new ExtractParameters(fileStream, "doc1")
            {
                ExtractFormat = ExtractFormat.Text,
                ExtractOnly = false
            });
}

solr.Commit();
```

Sorry for the trouble. I hope however that others will find this useful.

Comment: Very useful information -> it works for me.

Comment: Can you post your IndexDocument class? Thanks!

Comment: In order to use ExtractParameters you need SolrNet > 0.3.1 ("Install-Package SolrNet -Pre")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using the [SolrNet](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet) client. It supports the ExtractingRequestHandler.

Comment: I use SolrNet already but didn't know that ExtractingRequestHandler was supported. Is there some sort of documentation on this?

Comment: I've been all over the SolrNet documentation and it seems that it is only supported in the latest beta release. I would still like an example just using an HttpWebRequest if it's possible.

Comment: Even though the version of SolrNet that supports this is a Beta release, it is completely stable and usable. I have been using SolrNet for over 2 years and have been running Beta releases in our production environments without any issues. For an example, I would explore the SolrNet source - https://github.com/mausch/solrnet as I am know it is doing an HttpWebRequest to call Solr, so you should be able to follow what it is doing.

Comment: I have myself used SolrNet for 2 years but never used the beta releases before. I guess I should do that from now on. I just realised as well that the source-code is available at github so I'll look into that if necessary. Thanks for your help Paige.